# How to test a React app using context/provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-context

I develop a web application that leverages React Context. Now, I would like to test it but my test doesn't work. I would like to show a decline button in case an entry is for the current user. I want to test the component EventCard.

I have an AuthProvider in which I am handling the login and logout with a backend API. The API returns a user object if the login has been successful and I am storing the user object in a cookie so it survives the session. Now, I would like to simulate in my test, that the user is logged in and the user objects exists, but somehow the relevant `personId` is always `undefined`. How can I test with React's testing-library when I make use of React Context?

My test looks like this:

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { EventCard } from "../EventCard";
import { stdEventRequest } from "../../helpers/standard-request-for-tests";
import { AuthProvider, useAuth, withAuth } from "../../context/auth/AuthProvider";
import { FC } from "react";
import { CookieUniversalProvider } from "@shopify/react-cookie";

/**
 * A summary of an event should look something like this:
 * 
 * ============================================================================
 * John Doe (10:30)
 * Guitar [x] (a decline button)
 * Please let your leader know why you can't make it []  [if volunteer clicks Decline]
 * -------------------------------------------------
 * ============================================================================
 */

it('should show a decline button if current user', () => {
    const Component: FC = withAuth(() => {
      const auth = useAuth();
      jest.spyOn(auth, 'getUserData').mockReturnValue({
        personId: 123,
        ...
      });

      return (
        <CookieUniversalProvider>
          <AuthProvider>
            <EventCard request={{
              personId: 123,
              personName: 'John Doe',
              positionId: 10,
              positionName: 'Guitar',
            }} />
            personId: { auth.getUserData().personId }
          </AuthProvider>
        </CookieUniversalProvider>
      )
    });

    render(<Component />);

    const positionElement = screen.getByText(/Guitar/i);
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    expect(positionElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

I added `personId: { auth.getUserData().personId }` to check if my `spyOn` function is working. And it shows the expected result of `123`.

My EventCard component looks like this:

```js
export const EventCard = ({request}: EventCardProps) => {
  const { getUserData } = useAuth();
  
  return (
    <View>
      personId: {getUserData().personId}
      {request.personId === getUserData().personId ? (<>
        <Text fontWeight={600}>
          {request.positionName}
          <AcceptDeclineButton category="decline" />
        </Text>
        </>) : (<>
        <Text fontSize='small'>
          {statusToName(request)}
        </Text>
        <Text fontSize='small'>
          {request.positionName}
        </Text>
      </>)}
    </View>
  );
}
```

And again, I added the line `personId: {getUserData().personId}` to check if my `jest.spyOn` works and it doesn't. It returns undefined.